# assembly reference for data context in C#

Tags: linq-to-entities

i am new to linq. how to get reference for REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTs  in MVC.

error "var foreignKeys = from REF_CONST in datacontext.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTs"